# Kendo UI Grid / get detailgrid from parent row

Tags: jsp, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

next kendo problem.

I know how to expand a row in the Main/Mastergrid but how to get the detailGrid after the row expand?

Expand the row with:

```
function dataBound(e){
      ...
     $("#gridID").data("kendoGrid").expandRow(row);
}
```

After the expand i want to find an item in this detailGrid.

Is there an Event after row is expanded ?
Event databound on the detailgrid is not called!

Thanks for help

Comment: The event is `DetailExpand`, it is fired once the detail is expanded, as you may have guessed. Could you show more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

**The Main Grid:**

```
<kendo:grid name="gridMain" detailTemplate="detailGrid"   detailExpand="detailExpand" dataBound="expand" >
</kendo:grid>
```

**Detail Grid:**

```
  <kendo:grid name="detailGrid_#=ID#" detailExpand="detailExpand">
</kendo:grid>
```

**JS Main databound:**

```
function expand(e){
    var id= ${param.id}+"";
    $.each(e.sender.dataSource.data(), function (idx, elem) {
        if (elem.ID == id) {
            index = Math.floor(idx / e.sender.dataSource.pageSize() + 1);
            if ( index != e.sender.dataSource.page() ) {
                  e.sender.dataSource.page(index);
                  var row = $("#gridMain")
                                       .data("kendoGrid")
                                       .tbody
                                       .find("tr[data-uid='" + elem.uid + "']");
                  $("#gridMain").data("kendoGrid").expandRow(row);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**JS DetailGrid detailExpand:**

```
function detailExpand(e){
            console.log("detailExpand");
            console.log(e);
           //where is the detail Datasource ? 
        }
```

**Console.log output detailExpand:**

```
Object{
   Object detailRow{..}
   Object masterRow{..}
   Object sender{..}
}
```

From sender i get the main Datasource but where to get the detail Datasource